# _cacache is not a legal HTTP header value

Tags: node.js, gulp, cmd

При установке проекта gulp возникает ошибка

> D:\Alex\programming\myProject>npm i gulp --save-dev
>   npm ERR! C:\Users\Selom\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ **_cacache is not a legal HTTP header value**
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Selom\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-06-03T12_29_26_913Z-debug.log

Перешел в папку `npm-cache`, а там все три папки начинаются с нижнего подчеркивания. Изменил название **_cacache** на **cacahe**. Все получилось, но в папке создалась новая папка **_cacache** и при последующей установке sass выдает такую же ошибку. И приходится снова менять название. Уверен, что это плохо кончится.
Подскажите, как это можно решить?

**log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok 
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'i',
1 verbose cli   'gulp',
1 verbose cli   '--save-dev' ]
2 info using npm@5.0.0
3 info using node@v8.0.0
4 silly install loadCurrentTree
5 silly install readLocalPackageData
6 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for gulp@latest C:\Users\Selom\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache is not a legal HTTP header value
7 verbose stack TypeError: C:\Users\Selom\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache is not a legal HTTP header value
7 verbose stack     at sanitizeValue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\headers.js:24:11)
7 verbose stack     at Headers.set (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\headers.js:141:38)
7 verbose stack     at addCacheHeaders (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\cache.js:253:14)
7 verbose stack     at cacache.get.info.then.then.info (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\cache.js:57:9)
7 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
7 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
7 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
7 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
7 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
7 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
7 verbose stack     at Promise._resolveCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:432:57)
7 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:524:17)
7 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
7 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
7 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
7 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
8 verbose cwd D:\Alex\programming\myProject
9 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
10 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "gulp" "--save-dev"
11 verbose node v8.0.0
12 verbose npm  v5.0.0
13 error C:\Users\Selom\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache is not a legal HTTP header value
14 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "gulp project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Alex",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Дайте лог и package.json

Comment: Все добавил ...

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: не знаю пока, помогло или нет. Но большое спасибо, вы сегодня меня выручаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не связано с gulp. Я столкнулся точно с такой же проблемой при переходе на Node 8 & npm 5. В npm 4 всё работало, а после обновления не ставится ни один пакет.

Установка самых последних версий (node 8.1.0 & npm 5.0.3) не помогла. В репозитории npm нашел обсуждение этого бага:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17008

Они его уже починили, но пока не выложили в продакшн (обещают сделать в течение недели). Временный фикс - поставить canary-версию npm (npmc):
`npm i -g npmc`, и использовать команду `npmc` вместо `npm`. В моем случае это сработало.

Также можно установить `Yarn` (https://yarnpkg.com/en/) и добавлять пакеты через `yarn add` или перейти на седьмую версию `Node` - всё должно сработать.

Желаю удачи!

Comment: Большое спасибо! Воспользуюсь вашим советом в первую же возможность. До этого я справлялся с помощью `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: и Вам спасибо! я еще пробовал вручную удалять папку ` _cacache`, и тогда тоже работало. наверное, `npm cache clean --force` как раз это и делает:) однако все эти уловки явно не для повседневного использования, кэш ведь помогает делать меньше запросов к удаленным ресурсам. короче, ждем обновления npm.

Answer (score 0):

Все починили.Обновись.

```
npm i -g npm
```

Comment: Спасибо за хорошую новость!